# Using Webpack to add JavaScript module to ASP.NET MVC app

Tags: javascript, asp.net, node.js, asp.net-mvc, webpack

I'm trying to use [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) to create a couple of simple modules in an ASP.NET MVC 5 Visual Studio 2015 project. Following instructions on the Webpack site, I downloaded the latest version of Node.js. Then using the Node command prompt, changed to my project's folder. There, I ran this command to install Webpack locally:

```
npm install webpack --save-dev
```

It created a package.json file in the root of my project:

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^2.4.1"
  }
}
```

Note that the project already has jQuery and Bootstrap as bundles via the `BundleConfig.cs`, which are then referenced on `_Layout.cshtml`; hence they're available on all pages of the app.

Now I'd like to create a very simple test to see how to create and require modules using Webpack; once I understand it better, I can add more complex modules. I've been reading about code-splitting: https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting-async/ but it's still not clear how you do this.

The function `test` requires function `isEmpty`. I'd like to define `isEmpty` as a module and then use it with `test`.

```
var test = function(value){
    return isEmpty(value);
};

var isEmpty = function(value) {
    return $.trim(value).length === 0 ? true : false;
};
```

This article has been helping: http://developer.telerik.com/featured/webpack-for-visual-studio-developers/

The [Webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/) mentions `import()` and also `require.ensure()`. How do I use Webpack to modularize the `isEmpty` code and then use it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Webpack allows you to use the [commonJS](http://www.commonjs.org/) approach for [dependency management](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#components/sidebar/sidebar.jsx) which Node.js uses, so if you have experience with Node.js it's very similar. 
 If not have a look at this [article](https://blog.risingstack.com/node-js-at-scale-module-system-commonjs-require/) on the module system or the [spec](http://www.commonjs.org/specs/modules/1.0/) for a description of the module system.

For this problem I will assume all files are in the same directory.  I think you will need to first move the isEmpty code into a separate file maybe isEmpty.js and change it's structure a bit so that it looks like this:

```
module.exports = function(value) {
    return $.trim(value).length === 0 ? true : false;
};
```

then your test function can be moved into a separate test.js file and you can require the isEmpty module and use it like this:

```
var isEmpty = require('./isEmpty');
var test = function(value){
    return isEmpty(value);
};
```

You will probably have to do something about the dependency on $ (I'm guessing jquery?) but I think that can be handled with [shimming](https://webpack.js.org/guides/shimming/)

If you have a number of functions you can do something like:

**someFunctions.js**

```
var self = {};

self.Double = function(value){
    return value*2;
}

self.Triple = function(value){
    return value*3;
}

module.exports = self;
```

useFunctions.js

```
var useFunctions = require('./someFunctions');
var num = 5;
console.log(useFunctions.Double(num));
console.log(useFunctions.Triple(num));
```

Comment: Thanks, @Gun. A follow-up: Is it possible with CommonJS to have a bunch of functions in one file and require/use them in another, or must each function reside in its own file?

Comment: Added to original answer

Comment: Thanks, @Gun. One challenge: I keep getting the error `Module name ... has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])`.

Comment: Are you using lodash or underscore? if so you may have to shim it as well

Comment: To tell you the truth, @Gun, I'm kinda lost! In ASP.NET MVC, do I need to add the node_modules folder to the project? I might be using underscore but not sure. Whatever it is, it's not happy! Just want to get a basic setup so I can break my code into modules. Don't care about minimization, etc.

Comment: @Alex ignore the lodash and underscore comment, I saw _. which looked like underscore syntax. I think this is down to the asynchronous way webpack is loading the modules and the error seems to point to that 'Module name ... has not been loaded yet'.  Have a look at https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html as I think it has  a good example which may help

Comment: Thanks, @Gun. Looking at it. Much appreciated it :)

Comment: If there was a way to give you extra points on this, I would :)

Comment: happy to help :D